# Motherboard For Overclocking An i7 6700K?

Tags: motherboard, desktop

I am will be overclocking my Intel i7 6700K to 4.6 GHz and I am looking for a solid motherboard to go with it. Currently, I am considering the Asus Maximus VIII Hero (https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/) as I know that the previous motherboard (Asus Maximus VII Hero) was very good and I have had a good experience with Asus so far. Could anyone recommend any other motherboards?

***Must:***

- M.2 support.
- USB 3.1 support.
- ATX form factor.
- Under £200.

Comment: What does this motherboard *not* do that you'd like another one to do?

Comment: This is a very good motherboard, I would just like to see if anyone had any other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two *good* options here both being delivered by ASUS.

1. Your suggestion, the **[Maximus VIII Hero](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/)**.

   - 4x **DDR4** DIMMs Max **64 GB** Upto **3800mhz**
   - 1x **M.2**
   - 6x **Sata 6**
   - 2x **Sata Express**
   - Ample USB
2. At £40 cheaper, the **[Maximus VIII Ranger](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-RANGER/specifications/)**.

   - 4x **DDR4** DIMMs Max **64 GB** Upto **3400mhz**
   - Same  storage as the former.
   - Ample USB

It may be worth the extra £40 for you to go with the Ranger as it gives up nothing important and will leave you with money to spend elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your budget I would recommend exactly this model which you presented. But there are few other options.

**Cheaper:**

- [ASUS Maximus VIII Ranger](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-RANGER/specifications/) -> [£138 on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asus-MAXIMUS-VIII-RANGER-Motherboards/dp/B0126R35ME) - around £40 cheaper than Hero and it actually meets all your requirements.

**More expensive:**

This are top end motherboards for overvlocking Skylake maybe it is worth to save more money and buy best possible option if you have top end CPU.

- [ASUS Maximus VIII Formula](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-VIII-FORMULA/specifications/) -> [£305 on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Asus-Maximus-VIII-Formula-Motherboard/dp/B01A9GK4EQ)
- [MSI Z170A XPOWER Gaming Titanium Edition](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170A-XPOWER-GAMING-TITANIUM-EDITION.html#hero-overview) -> [£300 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014PXH3CU)

Comment: I really *don't* recommend blowing 305 euros on a board. Unless you need 11 USB 3.0 ports (you don't) it's a complete waste of money.